# Cannot get this button dropdown in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdown, card

I am working with classToggle to modify the css and show a text that is hidden behind an image.
Already made to work the button animation and a text that appears above the image. But cannot get the .dropped element to change the class.

JQUERY

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var boton = $(".boton");
        boton.click(function () {
            // Boton
            $(this).toggleClass("drop-rotate");
            boton.not(this).removeClass("drop-rotate");


            const titulo = $(this).closest(".c-card").children(".card").children(".texto");


            titulo.toggleClass("active-text");
            not(titulo).removeClass("active-text");


            const desc = $(this).closest(".c-card > dropped");
            desc.css("position", "relative");


            // desc.toggleClass("active");
            // not(desc).removeClass("active");
        });
    })
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="divisor">
        <div class="c-card">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="texto">
                    <h2>Whiterun</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="drop">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down boton"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="extended dropped">
                <h3>Descripción: </h3>
                <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quisquam
                    blanditiis nostrum laborum voluptas qui!
                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore expedita libero ipsam.
                    Voluptates, cum eum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result visually is like this [dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8MNg.png)

Comment: Any console errors? I'd be surprised if `not(titulo).removeClass("active-text");` isn't throwing an error.

Comment: I almost had it, but only one class changed (only text or only dropdown). Then I commented on vs code the not() part and now it works 100% Thanks mate!                    `const desc = $(this).closest(".c-card").children(".extended");
 desc.toggleClass("active");
// not(desc).removeClass("active")`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change your selector `.c-card > dropped` to `.c-card > .dropped` since you're selecting an element with the class `dropped` not an element of type `dropped`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. But isn't working either. I also tried with the code above, but no success                                                                                                                                         `var desc = $(this).closest(".c-card").children(".dropped");
desc.toggleClass("active");
not(desc).removeClass("active");`